# Compose key sequence for 'almost equal to' U2248 character stopped working in Fedora 37

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, compose-key

In Fedora I used to type the ≈ (U2248) pretty much on the daily basis.
I did it by pressing the Compose Key (<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> in my case) and then the <kbd>~</kbd> key twice.

But several months ago it stopped working.

**The compose key works**: it types other symbols correctly, e.g. 450⁰ and when I try to use the <kbd>~</kbd> it also causes the cursor to go into a sort-of waiting mode. But when I press the <kbd>~</kbd> the second time: the 'waiting mode' is canceled and no text has been entered (just like when the user typed an invalid compose key sequence).

So it's not an issue with the compose key.

Could anyone suggest something? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is IBus ignoring your /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose file.

You can re-define combinations directly in your ~/.XCompose file.
I used file from https://github.com/kragen/xcompose/blob/master/dotXCompose
It contains many combinations, including Compose~~ as ≈

Comment: Thank you, first for reminding me about this. Now, 6 months later — it works. In order to accept the answer, I have first to try if it works. I'll try to redefine ~~ with a !!!, for instance

Comment: This did the trick for me, too! Note: run `ibus restart` to apply the changes